# Get value of following row based on column w/o use of variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a database that tracks actions that users take. What I want to do is create a new column (follow_up) that populates based on the next action that a user takes during their session, i.e. the next event_id within a session. Unfortunately I do not have the ability to use or create variables - which obviously makes this more complicated as I cannot create a row number variable.

My data looks like:

```
Session ID | Event_ID | Action  
1          | 1        | Action A  
1          | 2        | Action B  
2          | 3        | Action A  
1          | 4        | Action C  
2          | 5        | Action C  
2          | 6        | Action A  
3          | 7        | Action B  
1          | 8        | Action A  
2          | 9        | Action C  
3          | 10       | Action C
```

What I want my final data set to look like is:

```
Session_ID | Event_ID | Action   | Follow_Up  
1          | 1        | Action A | Action B  
1          | 2        | Action B | Action C  
2          | 3        | Action A | Action C  
1          | 4        | Action C | Action A  
2          | 5        | Action C | Action A  
2          | 6        | Action A | Action C  
3          | 7        | Action B | Action C  
1          | 8        | Action A | Null  
2          | 9        | Action C | Null  
3          | 10       | Action C | Null
```

this code to pull this data is quite simple. Adding in the follow_up column has proven difficult

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Event_Id` is unique and incrementing, you can get the `Follow_Up` column like this:

```
select 
  t.*,
  (
    select Action from tablename
    where Event_Id = (
      select min(Event_Id) from tablename
      where Session_id = t.Session_id and Event_id > t.Event_id
    )  
  ) Follow_Up
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wxqV4C79wTK8vcZU4bHcg7/0).
Results:

```
| Session_ID | Event_ID | Action   | Follow_Up |
| ---------- | -------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1          | 1        | Action A | Action B  |
| 1          | 2        | Action B | Action C  |
| 2          | 3        | Action A | Action C  |
| 1          | 4        | Action C | Action A  |
| 2          | 5        | Action C | Action A  |
| 2          | 6        | Action A | Action C  |
| 3          | 7        | Action B | Action C  |
| 1          | 8        | Action A |           |
| 2          | 9        | Action C |           |
| 3          | 10       | Action C |           |
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow_up column populates based on the next action that a user takes during their session, i.e. the next event_id within a session using subquery

```
select 
  Session_ID,
  Event_ID ,
  Action,
  (select Action from test t1 
   where t1.Event_ID>t.Event_ID and t1.Session_ID=t.Session_ID  
   limit 1) Follow_up
from test t;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svGMffct6rEStwtX5ho1DL/3)